# Hong Kong visa for overseas Chinese

Tags: visas, eu, hong-kong, chinese-citizens

My girlfriend and I will be traveling to China and Hong Kong next month. I am an EU citizen and she is a Chinese citizen with permanent residence in the EU. For me the case is clear (I need to get a visa for Mainland China), but we are unsure about her.

Our route is going to be EU -> China -> HK -> China -> EU. We will get to HK via train and probably stay there for a few days (< 7) and then fly back to China (1.5 days) only to go back to EU. What travel document does she need to go to HK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tom is correct for the "visa" type, she did in fact need an Entry Permit.

However, it seems that many different ways are in place to obtain that permit. The immigration department as linked above (http://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/overseas-chinese-entry-arrangement.html#c) states 4 weeks processing time (upon arrival of the documents). Shanghai residents can (pre-)apply online for an HK entry permit, which takes 10 days processing. And at the embassy here they did the permit in just one week (and a 10€ processing fee).

Answer (score 3):

She needs an Entry Permit for Social Visits to Hong Kong.

http://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/overseas-chinese-entry-arrangement.html#c